# Bypass 'ondevicemotion' deprecation warning in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm building a web app, which involves detection of shaking event for a mobile device:

```
if (this.hasDeviceMotion) { window.addEventListener('devicemotion', this, false); }
```

I'm using [shake.js plugin](https://github.com/alexgibson/shake.js/) by Alex Gibson.

When testing my app in Chrome desktop browser I'm getting this warning:

`The devicemotion event is deprecated on insecure origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.`

In this link there's this text:

`We want to start applying the concepts in https://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/powerfulfeatures/ to features that have already shipped and which do not meet the (new, not present at the time) requirements. We want to start by requiring secure origins for these existing features:
Device motion / orientation
EME
Fullscreen
Geolocation
getUserMedia()...`

Even though it currently deprecated on desktop Chrome, knowing the guys in Mountain View I'm sure it will shortly be deprecated on mobile Chrome and Android Webview too.

My app is hosted on a server without secure connection, just HTTP. Is there a way to bypass this warning and have a shake detection in my app with HTTP connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to bypass this warning on unsecured origins and you are correct it will be deprecated on all platforms that we are able to auto-update.  Right now it is a deprecation warning only and has not been pushed to be a full removal yet.  We don't have a timescale as to when exactly it will be removed.

Comment: Thank you very much for elaborated answer!

Comment: Question: Why is device orientation considered a "powerful feature" and why is it being deprecated? Surely not just to passively-agressaively force people into HTTPS by removing useful but not dangerous functionality...

Answer (score 2):

The best way to bypass the deprecation is to move your application to HTTPS.

Many browsers are going to deprecate plain HTTP in order to make the web more secure. You should follow this trend and make your application support HTTPS. It's not hard though, there are free SSL certificates coming ( [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) ).